# Check if Campaign Has Changes

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm currently working with Adwords API and I like to ask if there is a way on how can check if a campaign has changed? (Campaigns's name, keywords, etc etc...) As far as I researched the only way to check is by using the customer sync services, but it only checks for the campaign's common settings. Keywords and Text Ads are not included. I'm using Java by the way.

Comment: Using customer sync services we can get ids of Keywords and Text Ads as well.Check the following code: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords_axis/src/main/java/adwords/axis/v201502/accountmanagement/GetAccountChanges.java

Comment: adGroupChanges.getChangedAds() and adGroupChanges.getChangedCriteria() will return the ids.